# Enforce search match multiple parameters

Tags: categories, search, eager-loading, products

I actually found this code on here [Search Form with Craft Commerce](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/search-form-with-craft-commerce). I had a problem with this code pulling up products that didn't match, and then after creating a new product it worked for a bit and then broke and continued to only pull up the same ones, even if I got rid the values inside with[].

So two questions, how do I enforce that the product has to match BOTH criteria in the with[] and does anyone have any clue about why it would stop refreshing products? I've tried clearing cache in both browser and craftcms.

I apologize if this has been asked before, I've been through multiple previously asked questions with little luck.

```
{% set spec = craft.request.getParam('a') %}
{% set spec2 = craft.request.getParam('b') %}
{% set category = craft.categories.group('productSpecs') %}
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
            relatedTo: category,
             with: [
                spec,
                spec2,
            ], 
            order: "title asc",
        }) %}
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `with` does. Or I am. Ha!

From what I understand `with` is for eager loading, but doesn't control anything in the relation itself. I don't think your relation makes any sense either because all you'll do is substitute a string into your spec variables.

Try something more like:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        CONDITION1,
        CONDITION2
    ],
    with: [
        fieldYouWantToShow,
        otherFieldYouWantToShow,
    ], 
    order: "title asc",
}) %}
```

And your conditionals should be something like:

```
{ targetElement: category },
{ sourceElement: craft.entries.section('reviews').status(null) }
```

The bottom example here is what you're needing: https://craftcms.com/docs/relations

Comment: I am with you Matt, `with` is for eager loading related elements. And before implementing it, @DarrylHardin needs to get the `relatedTo` param setup correctly for his needs. A good blog post on that topic that I can recommend: https://www.webstoemp.com/blog/combined-searches-and-filters-craft-cms/